# Prove that $(p \to q) \to (\neg q \to \neg p)$ is a tautology using the law of logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm new to discrete maths and I have been trying to solve this:

> Decide whether $$(p \to q) \to (\neg q \to \neg p)$$ is a tautology or not by using the law of logical equivalence

I have constructed the truth table and concluded that it is indeed a tautology. However, I am having difficulty proving it using the law of logical equivalence.
I can only realize that I can use $$(p \to q ) \equiv (\neg p \lor q)$$ but after that I have no idea how to continue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ( ¬q → ¬p ) ≡ ( ¬¬ q ∨ ¬p ) ≡ ( q ∨ ¬p ) ≡ ( ¬p ∨ q )

Comment: By *Double Negation* and *Commutativity*, $¬ p ∨ q$ is equivalent to $¬¬ q ∨ ¬ p$.

Comment: Sorry. I really do not know what are you saying about @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: $\neg q\implies \neg p$ is just a contrapositive of a conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of reasoning may help:

$\qquad\begin{align}
(p\to q)\to(\neg q\to\neg p)&\equiv\neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor(q\lor\neg p)&&\text{material implication}\\[1em]
&\equiv\neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor(\neg p\lor q)&&\text{commutativity}\\[1em]
&\equiv \neg M\lor M&&{M:\neg p\lor q}\\[1em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}&&\text{negation law}
\end{align}$

Is the above clear? It makes minimal use of other logical equivalences.

Comment: still a little bit not clear on the third statement  ¬M∨M
what do it mean by M : ¬ p ∨ q ?

Comment: It's just to help you see that you have a statement of the form $\neg M\lor M$ which clearly must be true. The letter $M$ can be stand for any compound statement you want.

Comment: @AhShing The justification, $(M: \neg p\vee q)$, reads "we defined a new symbol, $M$, to be equivalent to $\neg p\vee q$, so we could use substitution."

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  Now i finally get it. Thank you for your help :D @GrahamKemp

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the logical inferences you have available. One way is to note that
$$
(p\rightarrow q)\equiv(\neg q\rightarrow\neg p)\qquad\text{(contrapositive)}
$$
so your original expression is equivalent to
$$
(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(p\rightarrow q)
$$
and if we let $r=(p\rightarrow q)$ we have $r\rightarrow r$, which we either know is true or if you don't have that equivalence you can use material implication to get $(r\rightarrow r)\equiv (\neg r\lor r)$, which is true by inverse for OR.

Comment: wow now i finally understand thanks for the explanation :D

Answer (score 0):

They're indeed equivalent (implication goes both ways). In fact

$$
p\Rightarrow q \equiv \neg(p \land \neg q)
$$
and

$$
\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p \equiv \neg (\neg q \land \neg \neg p)\equiv \neg (p \land \neg q)
$$

So the two are equal, and therefore one implies the other.

Comment: okay so they are implies each other.
But what are the exactly the steps or laws I can use to prove it as tautology ?

Comment: If this does not convince you, you can simply write down the truth table, for all possible values for $p$ and $q$ and see what's the output. It will always be T. In fact, there is no way that the left hand side is T and the right hand side is F, because we showed that they are the same statement.